# How to combine $in and $elemMatch properly with MongoDB (PyMongo)

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

In my database, I've got data stored according to the following scheme:

```
{'_id': ...,
 'names': [{'first': ...,
            'last': ...},
           {'first': ...,
            'last': ...},
           ...
           ],
...
}
```

Now, in my program, I get a list of names according to the following scheme:

```
name_list = [(first_name1, last_name1), (first_name2, last_name2), ...]
```

What I want, is to find all documents where any of these combinations of first/last name found in `name_list` are contained in the `names` array.

If I'd have just one name to check (instead of a list), I'd use the following query:

```
query = {'names':
                 {'$elemMatch':
                      {'first_name': first_name,
                       'last_name': last_name}
                  }}
```

So I could supply this query for every name in the list, doing something like:

```
all_results = []
for first_name, last_name in name_list:
    rv := # Result from query
    # combine all_results and rv
```

But I feel like there should be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multi-elem match query could be created from `name_list` using [**`$or`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) and [**`$elemMatch`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) which works in a way to find the documents where any of those first/last combination matches.

**Query:** considering `name_list` to be

```
//[(first_name1, last_name1), (first_name2, last_name2), (first_name3, last_name3)]

db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      names: {
        $elemMatch: {
          first: "first_name1",
          last: "last_name1"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      names: {
        $elemMatch: {
          first: "first_name2",
          last: "last_name2"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      names: {
        $elemMatch: {
          first: "first_name3",
          last: "last_name3"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Is this the most idomatic way of doing this? I came across this solution before, but generating a query like this, especially long ones which could have, for example, 200 names, feels a little icky.

Comment: Had considered `name_list` being very large & initally wanted to use `$in` op on flattened array of `first_name` and `last_name` fields but that does quite get the results as it would get results of cross combinations too not only the pairs. Let the code work for you *by interating and prepping query object (even large so)*. Also you could wait for other answers to come that might be better than this and analyze.

Comment: I meant doesn't quite get the results at above comment :p